# Scala & Play Websockets: Storing messages exchanged

Tags: scala, playframework, websocket, playframework-2.0, akka

I started playing around scala and came to this particular boilerplate of web socket chatroom in scala.

They use `MessageHub.source()` and `BroadcastHub.sink()` as their Source and Sink for sending the messages to all connected clients.

The example is working fine for exchanging messages as it is.

```
private val (chatSink, chatSource) = {
  // Don't log MergeHub$ProducerFailed as error if the client disconnects.
  // recoverWithRetries -1 is essentially "recoverWith"
  val source = MergeHub.source[WSMessage]
    .log("source")
    .recoverWithRetries(-1, { case _: Exception ⇒ Source.empty })

  val sink = BroadcastHub.sink[WSMessage]
  source.toMat(sink)(Keep.both).run()
}

private val userFlow: Flow[WSMessage, WSMessage, _] = {
 Flow.fromSinkAndSource(chatSink, chatSource)
}

def chat(): WebSocket = {
  WebSocket.acceptOrResult[WSMessage, WSMessage] {
    case rh if sameOriginCheck(rh) =>
      Future.successful(userFlow).map { flow =>
        Right(flow)
      }.recover {
        case e: Exception =>
          val msg = "Cannot create websocket"
          logger.error(msg, e)
          val result = InternalServerError(msg)
          Left(result)
      }

    case rejected =>
      logger.error(s"Request ${rejected} failed same origin check")
      Future.successful {
      Left(Forbidden("forbidden"))
      }
  }
}
```

I want to store the messages that are exchanged in the chatroom in a DB.

I tried adding map and fold functions to source and sink to get hold of the messages that are sent but I wasn't able to.

I tried adding a Flow stage between MergeHub and BroadcastHub like below

```
val flow = Flow[WSMessage].map(element => println(s"Message: $element"))
source.via(flow).toMat(sink)(Keep.both).run()
```

But it throws a compilation error that cannot reference toMat with such signature.

Can someone help or point me how can I get hold of messages that are sent and store them in DB.

Link for full template:

https://github.com/playframework/play-scala-chatroom-example

Comment: Please add some (prototype) code to show how you tried to add a flow stage. Also show the definition of the flow stage taking care of saving data in the DB.

Comment: @FredericA. Added the code where i tried adding the flow stage. I might be wrong as I am new to this.

Comment: Did you really use this code for the flow? It's clearly wrong and would explain the compilation error

Comment: Yes, I am not sure what to do to achieve this. Your guidance is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at your flow:

```
val flow = Flow[WSMessage].map(element => println(s"Message: $element"))
```

It takes elements of type `WSMessage`, and returns nothing (`Unit`). Here it is again with the correct type:

```
val flow: Flow[Unit] = Flow[WSMessage].map(element => println(s"Message: $element"))
```

This will clearly not work as the sink expects `WSMessage` and not `Unit`.

Here's how you can fix the above problem:

```
val flow = Flow[WSMessage].map { element =>
  println(s"Message: $element")
  element
 }
```

Not that for persisting messages in the database, you will most likely want to use an async stage, roughly:

```
val flow = Flow[WSMessage].mapAsync(parallelism) { element =>
  println(s"Message: $element")
  // assuming DB.write() returns a Future[Unit]
  DB.write(element).map(_ => element)
 }
```

Comment: Thanks @Fredric A. That helps me understand how it works.

Comment: I have one more doubt, in the example which I gave, it works like sending the messages from one client to other clients. 
If I want to broadcast a message which is generated dynamically from time to time in server to all the clients, how would I do it?

Comment: I think you can achieve that by creating a new `Source` (that source is the server as you described). Now, if you understand that your existing `source.via(flow)` is a source, you now have 2 sources that you have to merge. You can for example do `source.via(flow).combine(serverEventsSource)(Merge).toMat(sink)(Keep.both).run()`